# What should I feed my kids for breakfast?

Tags: food

I have a 6-year-old boy and an 8-year-old girl. They currently eat sugary cereal for breakfast, but I'm looking for alternatives, particularly from experience.

What are healthier alternatives they will actually eat?

Comment: This would still probably be better asked at http://fitness.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This seems like the other one Ross posted about eating Bacon everyday...these could be combined...

Comment: I think this is quite appropriate for parenting.stackexchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My boys (four-year-old twins) eat mostly fresh fruit and berries, which they actually even prefer to candy at times.  Our Easter baskets are still half full because the boys lost interest in the overly-sweet candy and would ask for fruit instead.

In addition to the fruit, they usually also have vegetarian sausage patties and either whole grain toast with a non-hydrogenated vegetable spread or all-fruit spread, or else some whole grain cereal, usually dry or with a small amount of milk.

We've also been giving them drinkable yogurt mixed with milk since they were infants, once in the morning and once in the evening.

We also have less healthful meals from time to time, usually lots of bacon (the more expensive nitrate-free kind) and eggs on weekends, muffins that they help to bake at least once a week or so, and very rarely they'll have juice when we're out someplace.  My wife and I are recovering juice addicts so we try to keep it out of the house as much as possible, and the boys mostly just drink their yogurt and water.

The key thing for trying to get our kids to eat well has been to eat the same things ourselves as much as possible.  I grew up on sugary cereal and cheap, plentiful bacon and it wasn't until I was much older that I started to feel the difference in my own health when I ate better foods.  My kids already eat much, much better than I ever did, and are (I hope) acquiring tastes for the kinds of foods that will keep them healthy, growing up.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Lots of options here. I'll start experimenting :)

Comment: "Muffins that the kids helped to bake" - awesome. There is a great Blueberry Bran muffin recipe that goes down well.

Answer (score 4):

Kids should eat almost exactly what the adults do for any meal from a very young age, even if you don't eat at the same time.  If sugary cereal isn't good for you, it isn't good for them.  Parents lead by example and help children develop a broader palette.  The difference should be portion size and ratio of each food; A weight lifter dad needs a higher percentage of protein, and kids in general can use a bit more fat than adults.

Oatmeal and yogurt are great because they can be tuned to each person's taste while having a common experience and can be a way to experiment with new flavors.  "Today we are trying almonds.  Thats one of the flavors in honey nut cheerios."  "I liked the crunch.  What did you think of it?"  If they hesitate, let them help you make granola in the oven to see what goes into it.

If you don't think a 5 year old can develop interest in adult flavors, I have new anecdotes handy practically any week:  last night my 5 year old said "This tuna steak tastes like wood."  "Do you like it?" "Yes. Why does it taste like wood?"  "It was grilled on a ceder plank." [smile]

Answer (score 0):

My 5 year old really enjoys vanilla yogurt and whole wheat O's

Answer (score 0):

When not eating sugary cereal, they'll tend to eat sugary waffles or sugary pop-tarts. On occasion, a sugary donut or sugary muffin.

I kid. A bit. They do enjoy plain Cheerios and milk, and yogurt is always a favorite.